# incompatibility between Python 2.7 and 3

Tags: ubuntu, xubuntu

I am trying to installl Mininet-wifi and unfortunately it can't be installed

This is how it is displayed in my Ubuntu Virtual Machine. I am using Python 3.7.1

```
aristide@ubuntu:~/mininet-wifi$ sudo util/install.sh -Wlnfv
[sudo] password for aristide: 
Detected Linux distribution: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial i386
Ubuntu
python is version 2
Installing Mininet-WiFi dependencies
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
make is already the newest version (4.1-6).
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu1).
rfkill is already the newest version (0.5-1ubuntu3).
wireless-tools is already the newest version (30~pre9-8ubuntu1).
libnl-genl-3-dev is already the newest version (3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.12).
libnl-3-dev is already the newest version (3.2.27-1ubuntu0.16.04.1).
patch is already the newest version (2.7.5-1ubuntu0.16.04.1).
libevent-dev is already the newest version (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-matplotlib : Depends: python-dateutil but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-pyparsing (>= 1.5.6) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-tz but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-cycler but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                     Recommends: python-glade2 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: python-imaging but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: python-tk (>= 2.5.2-1.1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-numpy : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                         liblapack.so.3
 python-scipy : Depends: python-decorator but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                Depends: libgfortran3 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                         liblapack.so.3
                Recommends: python-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: python-imaging but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Looks to my like you need python 2.7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some missing dependencies in your system. This isn't about Mininet-WiFi at all. Have you ever checked sources.list? You may want to add  appropriated sources for the missing dependencies.